# Stop HTML Table Column with 100% Width from Text Wrapping Other Columns Unnecessarily

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table, nowrap

I have an HTML table (with 100% width) with three columns, the middle one with 100% width. It works fine, but it forces the left and right columns to text-wrap their contents, even if there is enough space on the screen to show them un-wrapped. The image below illustrates my problem. There is enough space to show "South America" and the third column whole, but the middle column forces them to wrap.

[image: Wrapping Columns]

Here is the code:

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>South America</td>
    <td style="width: 100%;">Green Beans</td>
    <td>$25,000 per kg</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to `nowrap`, and `table-layout: fixed` is not perfect. Is there a "proper" trick to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Flexbox and its states so you can easily solve your problem using the below code to fulfill your requirement.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    display: flex;
}

tr td {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>South America</td>
        <td>Green Beans</td>
        <td>$25,000 per kg</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```